# Why is plesk saying country hits for a website are coming from commercial (.com), Network (.net)

Tags: plesk

I have a website and it's being subject to hotlinking and I need to know why when I look at my web stats Plesk is saying that the country of origin for the traffic is .com, .net etc.

Comment: What is plesk and os versions ? what is used Awstats or Webalizer. In case of Awstats did you configure GeoIP plugin ? https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002097389

Comment: It's Plesk version V8.6.0 and I'm talking about the stats page built into Plesk. The plugin GeoIP is installed but for some reason, it is finding .com and .net as countries and I can't understand why.